# Is there a way to make Pandas melt and stack methods to generate same outputs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year',  'Player',   'Team', 'TeamName', 'Games',    'Pts',  'Assist',   'Rebound'],data=[[2015, 'Curry', 'GSW', 'Warriors', 79, 30.1, 6.7, 5.4],
       [2016, 'Curry', 'GSW', 'Warriors', 79, 25.3, 6.6, 4.5],
       [2017, 'Curry', 'GSW', 'Warriors', 51, 26.4, 6.1, 5.1],
       [2015, 'Durant', 'OKC', 'Thunder', 72, 28.2, 5.0, 8.2],
       [2016, 'Durant', 'GSW', 'Warriors', 62, 25.1, 4.8, 8.3],
       [2017, 'Durant', 'GSW', 'Warriors', 68, 26.4, 5.4, 6.8],
       [2015, 'Ibaka', 'OKC', 'Thunder', 78, 12.6, 0.8, 6.8],
       [2016, 'Ibaka', 'ORL', 'Magic', 56, 15.1, 1.1, 6.8],
       [2016, 'Ibaka', 'TOR', 'Raptors', 23, 14.2, 0.7, 6.8]])
```

If I use

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Year', 'Player','Team','TeamName'])
```

I got a melted version of this df.  I am trying to use
`df.stack(), df.unstack(), df.set_index(), df.reset_index()` to get the same output as the melted version, but I could not get it done.

Any suggestion on how to generate the same output from stack, unstack, set_index, reset_index as the melted version?  (Any other method beside these 4 cannot be used.)

Here is the most recent attempt.  I don't care the column names. But the value should be aligned.  I almost got it but the values are still swapped.

```
df.set_index(['Year', 'Player', 'Team', 'TeamName']).stack().reset_index()
```

Thanks.

Comment: The ordering of `stack` and `melt` tends to be different. Do you need the **exact** row ordering in the output, or is it okay so long as the data are all there?

Comment: Hi @ALollz,

I need exact same alignment and ordering.  Here is what I attempted so far, but the ordering is still messed up.

`df.set_index(['Year', 'Player', 'Team', 'TeamName']).stack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `set_index` + `stack` + `reset_index` to reproduce what a `melt` does. `melt` also renames the columns so we can take care of that too. And to deal with the ordering we'll need to do some modulus division.

This doesn't have all the bells and whistles of `melt`, but gets the basic job done for specifying only `id_vars`

```
import numpy as np

id_vars = ['Year', 'Player', 'Team', 'TeamName']

N = len(id_vars)                   # For renaming
N_ord = len(df.columns)-N          # For reordering

df = (df.set_index(id_vars)
        .stack(dropna=False)       # Melt keeps `NaN`
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={0: 'value', f'level_{N}': 'variable'}))

# Reorder to match `melt`
df = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.index%N_ord, kind='mergesort')].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    Year  Player Team  TeamName variable  value
0   2015   Curry  GSW  Warriors    Games   79.0
1   2016   Curry  GSW  Warriors    Games   79.0
2   2017   Curry  GSW  Warriors    Games   51.0
3   2015  Durant  OKC   Thunder    Games   72.0
...
34  2016   Ibaka  ORL     Magic  Rebound    6.8
35  2016   Ibaka  TOR   Raptors  Rebound    6.8
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the exact same ordering!  It seems like there is no way to get the exact same ordering with the melted one without using np.argsort.  If you know a way to strictly write it with only stack, unstack, set_index, and reset_index, please let me know.

Comment: There are probably several other ways, you could split and concat for instance. The issue is just they each raster through the DataFrame differently. `melt` goes down rows then across the columns not in `id_vars`. `stack` goes across the columns not in id_vars then down the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index(['Year', 'Player','Team','TeamName'], inplace=True)
df = df.stack().rename('value').reset_index()
df = df.rename({'level_4': 'variable'})
```

Now df is of the same shape as with the melt operation. With melt you get a column named 'variable' which in this case holds the labels 'games', 'pts', and the rest. With  stack.reset that column ends up being called 'level_4'. The rename fixes that.

Comment: Thanks very much!  However, the ordering is still similar to my attempt though.